# When importing modules written with tkinter and ttk, stuff doesn't work

Tags: python, tkinter, ttk

I'm new to programming, Python, this website, and actually using these kinds of websites in general, so hear me out.

I've been writing a module for a larger program using the tkinter module and ttk module, and when I import my own module into the main program, for some reason none of the ttk stuff works as it should. I mean, it appears, but the style I've written for it (s=ttk.Style(); s.configure...etc.) doesn't change it in anyway. When I run the module on its own, everything works fine. When it's imported into the main program, it just doesn't.

Not only this, but when using entry boxes, I've only just discovered that the way I'd been told to use them, with, for example, var=StringVar() as the textvariable (which again works fine when the module is run on its own), now just leaves the variable var as empty when var.get() is called. Now I've sorted this by just removing all mention of StringVar() (wish I'd known how redundant these really are), but I'd still like to know why importing them in to the main program causes them to malfunction so badly. I would give you some sample code but there's so much I'd struggle to be selective enough...

I'd appreciate any guidance you can offer.

EDIT: Would giving you something like this have helped?

stackoverflowmodule.py

```
import sys
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import time
from random import randint, choice

class Decimals():
    def Question1(self):
        DECFrame.destroy()
        frame1=ttk.Frame(DECmaster, height=height, width=width, style="NewFrame.TFrame")
        frame1.pack()
        Q1Label=ttk.Label(frame1, text="Question 1:", style="TitleLabel.TLabel")
        Q1Label.grid(column=0, row=0, pady=(50,0))     
        answer=StringVar()
        entry1=ttk.Entry(frame1, textvariable=answer)
        entry1.grid(column=0, row=1, pady=(200,0))
        # Typing in Hello should give a correct answer.
        def Question1Attempt():            
            attempt=answer.get()            
            if attempt!="Hello":
                print("Incorrect")
            else:
                print("Correct")
        button=ttk.Button(frame1, text="Ok", command=Question1Attempt)
        button.grid(column=0, row=2, pady=(30,0))


def Start():
    global DECmaster
    global s
    global DECFrame
    global DEC
    global width
    global height
    DECmaster = Tk()

    width=str(1000)
    height=str(800)
    x1=str(0)
    y1=str(0)

    DECmaster.geometry(width+"x"+height+"+"+x1+"+"+y1)
    DECmaster.configure(bg="#8afff0")

    s=ttk.Style()
    s.configure("NewFrame.TFrame", background="#8afff0")
    s.configure("TitleLabel.TLabel", foreground= "blue", background="#8afff0")

    DECFrame=ttk.Frame(DECmaster, style="NewFrame.TFrame")
    DECFrame.pack()

    TitleLabel=ttk.Label(DECFrame, text="Test for Decimals", style="TitleLabel.TLabel")
    TitleLabel.grid(column=1, row=0, pady=(50,0), sticky=N)

    DEC=Decimals()
    button=ttk.Button(DECFrame, text="Start", command=DEC.Question1)
    button.grid(column=2, row=2, pady=(200,0), sticky=N)

    DECmaster.mainloop()
```

stackoverflowprogram.py

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import time
import stackoverflowmodule



root = Tk()

width=str(1000)
height=str(800)
x1=str(0)
y1=str(0)
##width=str(1228)
##height=str(690)
##x1=str(-1)
##y1=str(-22)

root.geometry(width+"x"+height+"+"+x1+"+"+y1)
root.configure(bg="#8afff0")

s=ttk.Style()
s.configure("NewFrame.TFrame", background="#8afff0")
s.configure("TitleLabel.TLabel", foreground= "blue", background="#8afff0")

Testframe=ttk.Frame(root, height=height, width=width, style="NewFrame.TFrame")
Testframe.pack()
Titlelabel=ttk.Label(Testframe, text="Start Test:", style="TitleLabel.TLabel")
Titlelabel.grid(column=0, row=0, pady=(50,0))

def StartTest():
    stackoverflowmodule.Start()


button=ttk.Button(Testframe, text="Start", command=StartTest)
button.grid(column=0, row=1, pady=(100,0))

root.mainloop()
```

I realise there's an awful lot there, but I couldn't really demonstrate my point without it all. Thanks again.

Comment: Without seeing any code, it's hard to be sure, but my first guess is that you're creating a `tkinter.Tk` object in the module, and creating another one in the script that imports it. If so, either half of your code won't work properly (because it's using a `Tk` without a `mainloop`), or half your code won't even get run (because   the other one's `mainloop` doesn't return until you quit).

Comment: More importantly: Please provide source for a [stripped-down example](http://sscce.org) of a module and program that's enough to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: Aha... That sounds faimiliar... What's the alternative?

Comment: And oh ok... Thank you, as I've said, new to all this so appreciate the pointer.

Comment: Either the module or the script has to be the "main application" in Tk terms. Let me write an answer that gives an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The root of your problem is that you're creating more than once instance of `Tk`. A Tkinter app can only have a single instance of of the `Tk` class, and you must call `mainloop` exactly once. If you need additional windows you should create instances of `Toplevel` (http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/toplevel.htm).

If you want to create modules with reusable code, have your modules create subclasses of `Frame` (or `Toplevel` if you're creating dialos). Then, your main script will create an instance of `Tk`, and place these frames in the main window or in subwindows.

If you want to sometimes use your module as a reusable component and sometimes as a runnable program, put the "runnable program" part inside a special if statement:

```
# module1.py
import Tkinter as tk
class Module1(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        label = tk.Label(self, text="I am module 1")
        label.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)

# this code will not run if this module is imported
if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    m1 = Module1(root)
    m1.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
```

In the above code, if you run it like `python module1.py`, the code in that final if statement will run. It will create a root window, create an instance of your frame, and make that frame fill the main window.

If, however, you import the above code into another program, the code in the if statement will *not* run, so you don't get more than one instance of `Tk`.

Let's assume you have two modules like the above, and want to write a program that uses them, and each should go in a separate window.  You can do that by writing a third script that uses them both:

```
# main.py
import Tkinter as tk
from module1 import Module1
from module2 import Module2

# create the main window; every Tkinter app needs
# exactly one instance of this class
root = tk.Tk()
m1 = Module1(root)
m1.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)

# create a second window
second = tk.Toplevel(root)
m2 = Module2(second)
m2.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)

# run the event loop
root.mainloop()
```

With the above, you have code in two modules that can be used in three ways: as standalone programs, as separate frames within a single window, or as separate frames within separate windows.

Comment: Wow... Well thank you very much! What a fantastic answer, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can't create two instances of `tkinter.Tk`. If you do, one of two things will happen.

Most of the code in the script may just not run, because it's waiting for the module's `mainloop` to finish, which doesn't happen until you quit.

If you structure things differently, you'll end up with two `Tk` instances, only one of which is actually running. Some of the code in your script will happen to find the right `Tk` instance (or the right actual Tk objects under the covers), because there's a lot of shared global stuff that just assumes there's one Tk "somewhere or other" and manages to find. But other code will find the wrong one, and just have no effect. Or, occasionally, things will have the *wrong* effect, or cause a crash, or who knows what.

You need to put the top-level application in one place, either the module or the script that uses it, and have the other place access it from there.

---

One way to do this is to write the module in such a way that its code can be called with a `Tk` instance. Then, use the `__main__` trick so that, if you run the module directly as a script (rather than importing it from another script), it creates a `Tk` instance and calls that code. Here's a really simple example.

tkmodule.py:

```
from tkinter import *

def say_hi():
    print("Hello, world!")

def create_interface(window):
    hi = Button(window, text='Hello', command=say_hi)
    hi.pack()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = Tk()
    create_interface(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

tkscript.py:

```
from tkinter import *
import tkmodule

i = 0
def count():
    global i
    i += 1
    print(i)

def create_interface(window):
    countbtn = Button(window, text='Count', command=count)
    countbtn.pack()

root = Tk()
create_interface(root)
window = Toplevel(root)
tkmodule.create_interface(window)
root.mainloop()
```

Now, when you run `tkscript.py`, it owns one `Tk` instance, and passes it to its own `create_frame` and to `tkmodule.create_frame`. But if you just run `tkmodule.py`, *it* owns a `Tk` instance, which it passes to its own `create_frame`. Either way, there's exactly one `Tk` instance, and one main loop, and everyone gets to use it.

Notice that if you want two top-level windows, you have to explicitly create a `Toplevel` somewhere. (And you don't want to *always* create one in `tkmodule.py`, or when you run the module itself, it'll create a new window and leave the default window sitting around empty.)

---

Of course an even simpler way to do this is to put all of your GUI stuff into modules that *never* create their own `Tk` instance, and write scripts that import the appropriate modules and drive them.

Comment: I'm not quite sure that I understand your example... When I run it, after some adjustments to get rid of some errors, all I get is an empty window.

Comment: Ok, I've now got the buttons to display, but I still don't understand... really I'd prefer two windows, not just two frames!

Comment: Sorry, for that, you want `Toplevel`, not `Frame`. And you want to do something a bit fancy to make sure one of the two just creates a `Frame` rather than a `Toplevel` (because if they _each_ create a `TopLevel`, you'll end up with the default empty window, plus the two windows you want). Let me edit the code.