# How to import modules written with tkinter when button has command

Tags: tkinter

I want to have a generic Tk module that can be imported. I've read [When importing modules written with tkinter and ttk, stuff doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16531798/when-importing-modules-written-with-tkinter-and-ttk-stuff-doesnt-work) and it explained a lot, but the example doesn't have a button with a command.

My generic Tk module 'generic_tk_module.py' is:

```
from tkinter import Tk, ttk, Text
class AppWindow(ttk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        ttk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)   
        self.parent = parent
        self.makewidgets()

    def makewidgets(self):
        self.pack(side='top', fill='both', expand=True)

        btn_close = ttk.Button(self, text='Close', command=close)
        btn_close.grid(row=3, column=2, sticky='n', pady=4, padx=5)

        txw = Text(self)
        txw.grid(row=2, column=0, columnspan=2, rowspan=2, pady=5, padx=5, sticky=('nsew'))
        txw.configure(font=("consolas", 11), padx=20) 
        self.txw = txw

        self.columnconfigure(1, weight=1)
        self.rowconfigure(2, weight=1)

    def write(self, text):
        """Schrijf aan het einde van de tekst, en scroll eventueel."""
        self.txw.insert('end', text)

def close():
    root.destroy()

def main(window_handle):
    print("welcome message from the generic module ", file = window_handle)
    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = Tk()
    root.geometry("700x400")
    root.update()
    window_handle = AppWindow(root)
    main(window_handle)
```

And my calling module is:

```
from tkinter import Tk
from generic_tk_module import AppWindow

def main():
    root = Tk()
    root.geometry("700x400")
    root.update()
    window_handle = AppWindow(root)

    print("welcome message from the calling module", file = window_handle)
    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Of course, when one clicks btn_close an error occurs: name 'root' is not defined.

How should I set the function call for the Close button **command=close** and **def close()** in the generic module?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should place `close` as a method in your `App` class, and call `destroy` on `self.parent`:

```
def close(self):           # make sure to indent to match the class indentation
    self.parent.destroy()
```

then your button command should be:

```
command=self.close
```

You should also probably use `super` in the `__init__` of your `App`, instead of calling the superclass explicitly, but this is unrelated to your question:

```
super().__init__(parent)
```